# KVO infinite recurrence / loop

Tags: cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I want to be able to change a (calendar) event, which has a startDate and an endDate. There's also a duration.

1. When the user changes the endDate, the duration is updated.
2. When the user changes the startDate, the endDate changed according to the duration.
3. When the user changes the duration, the endDate changes.

This last action would trigger the first action, which would trigger the third, which would trigger the first, *ad infinitum* (or when the stack fills up).

Lines like the following, to change the values, cause this loop:

```
        [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:(interval%60)] forKeyPath:@"durationMinutes"];
        [self setValue:ed forKeyPath:@"endDate"];
```

To simply stop observing, and restart after a change, is not attractive since the values in the GUI won't get updated.
The question, then, is: **How can I safely (and elegantly) update one of two interdependent properties?**

Comment: I now have an instance variable (boolean) called timeIntervalChanged. I set it to TRUE when about to change the `duration` or `endDate`, and set it back to FALSE when done. The code to change `duration` and `endDate` immediately returns when the boolean is TRUE. It prevents the infinite recursion, but feels like an ugly solution.

Comment: Is this in a custom setter method? Something like `setStartDate:`?

Comment: No custom setter; the "problematic" code is in methods that get called by changes in value of the properties. These methods then calculate the changes of other properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass KVO notifications when necessary by using `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`. That sets the value but does not trigger any notifications. It also bypasses any custom setter you might have for the property. That should break the call cycle.

When using this method you generally want to call the "will change" and "did change" methods to ensure that the Core Data state is maintained. That is, something like:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"endDate"];
[self setPrimitiveValue:ed forKey:@"endDate"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"endDate"];
```

This avoids the need for a flag-- you just say, hey, set the value and no messing around, OK?

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to write custom setters so that they update the values only if they have changed:

For instance:

```
- (void)setDurationMinutes:(NSNumber *)minutes
{
    if (![minutes isEqual:self.durationMinutes])
    {
        _durationMinutes = minutes;
        self.endDate = [self.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:minutes * 60]; 
    }
}

- (void)setEndDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    if (![_endDate isEqualToDate:date])
    {
        _endDate = date;
        self.durationMinutes = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate] / 60;
    }
}
```

So now, when you set the minutes to a different value, it will update and set the end date.  End date will be different so it will update and set the duration.  However, this time the duration will be the same (since it was previously set) and it won't attempt to set itself or the end date again.

It also keeps your code nice and clean, and clear about what changes what and when.

Answer (score 1):

Combine all three into one method.

```
- (void)updateEndDate:(NSDate *)end
            startDate:(NSDate *)start
             duration:(NSNumber *)duration
{
  ... insert your update logic here
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"endDate"];
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"duration"];
  _endDate = end;
  _startDate = start;
  _duration = duration;
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"duration"];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"endDate"];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];
}
```

Call that method in your settors

```
-(void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)start
{
   [self updateEndDate:self.endDate startDate:start duration:self.duration];
}
```

KVO compliance requires you to specify that you are manually sending notifications for the properties

```
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString *)theKey
{

    BOOL automatic = NO;
    NSArray * manualKeys = @[@"endDate", @"startDate", @"duration"];
    if ([manualKeys containsObject:theKey])
    {
        automatic = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        automatic = [super automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:theKey];
    }
    return automatic;
}
```

Comment: I will try this too. I like the idea of everything in one method: it could live in `observeValueForKeyPath:...`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out I was fighting the system. I now calculate duration values on the fly, and act on changes using IBActions.

```
- (IBAction)changedEndDate:(id)sender
    if ( [_occurrence.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_occurrence.startDate] < 0 )
            _occurrence.startDate = _occurrence.endDate;

    long duration = ( [_occurrence.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_occurrence.startDate] ) / 60;
    [self.durationHoursTextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",duration/60]];
    [self.durationMinutesTextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",duration%60]];
}
- (IBAction)changedDurationOrStartDate:(id)sender
{
    long durH = [self.durationHoursTextField integerValue];
    long durM = [self.durationMinutesTextField integerValue];
    if ( durH < 0 )
    {
        durH = 0;
        [self.durationHoursTextField setStringValue:@"0"];
    }
    if ( durM < 0 )
    {
        durM = 0;
        [self.durationMinutesTextField setStringValue:@"0"];
    }
    long duration = durH * 3600 + durM * 60;
    _occurrence.endDate = [_occurrence.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:duration];
 }
```